# boundedness of infinite norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading Theorical Numerical Analysis of Atkinson & Han and I'm trying one excercise but I'm stuck.

On $C^1[a,b]$, define
$$
(f,g)_*=f(a)g(a)+\int_a^b f'(x)g'(x)\,dx,\quad\forall f,g\in C^1[a,b]
$$
and $\lVert f\rVert_*= \sqrt{(f,f)_*}$. Show that
$$
\lVert f\rVert_\infty\leq c\lVert f \rVert_*\quad\forall f\in C^1[a,b]
$$
for a suitable constant $c$.

I thought that Taylor expansion could be a way to prove but this didn't work. Any suggestion or hint?

Comment: First line typo? f(a)g(x)?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes, I already corrected

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not sure about what you are talking

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, thanks so much, I will respond the answers and vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant $$
(f,g)_*=f(a)g(a)+\int_a^b f'(x)g'(x)\,dx,\quad\forall f,g\in C^1[a,b]
$$

The inequality holds with $c=2\max \{1,\sqrt {b-a}\}$.

$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^{x} f'(t)dt$. So $|f(x)| \leq |f(a)|+\sqrt {\int_a^{x} f'(t)^{2}dt} \sqrt {b-a}$. But $|c+d| \leq 2\sqrt {c^{2}+d^{2}}$ for all real numbers $c$ and $d$. Hence, $|f(x)| \leq 2\sqrt {(f(a)^{2}+(b-a)\int_a^{x} f'(t)^{2}dt)}\leq c\|f\|_{*}$